# How to cross compile assimp(assert importer) to a platform like ps4 or XBox1

Tags: c++, playstation, xbox-one

I am trying to create a Game Engine for the PlayStation 4 and XBOX One for educational purposes and currently I am trying to use Assimp as a 3D model loader for this engine.

I need to compile assimp library for these consoles as these consoles use AMD APU's, before using it in the engine. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: assimp is an open source library, so you can download the code and compile it on the platform you want.

Comment: Hi Mohammed ...thanks a ton ... have you done it for any other platform apart from windows? like ios,android ..coz i just need to know the steps and pre requisites ..like what macros need to enabled ,disabled ..will the library compile for AMD APU's ..stuffs like that.

Comment: While I have not done it. Assimp is very well documented and has instruction on how to compile their library. http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/install.html

Comment: You're asking pretty strange questions for an "Indie Pro".

Comment: molbdnilo ..sometimes stuffs break and u r back to basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft and Sony offer custom compilers to developers to cross-compile code to their consoles. As of now, there are no public compilers that will do it: you need the first-party toolkit. Even if there was a compiler, you probably wouldn't be able to get the code running on the PS4 or the Xbox One because they will only execute signed code, and only Microsoft- and Sony-approved games can be signed and executed on consoles. Registered developers usually have access to special console hardware that will run unsigned code, but consumers don't. These kits are usually a lot more expensive, too.

Some consoles, especially the older ones, have community-supported unofficial SDKs with which you can program games, but they usually have been around for a while, because it takes some time to find a way to defeat code signing protection.

Comment: Hi Zneak ..thanx a lot ..i have no hindrances in my path (i.e the hindrances you mentioned ;-))..i will keep issues posted ..on my advance.

Comment: Well then, what's wrong with just compiling them normally along with the rest of your solution?

Comment: Can someone really let me know the steps to cross compile it.Its a first time i am doing.

Comment: The project ships with a CMake file, so you should ask CMake to create a VS project and change the target platform yourself. You won't find exact steps anywhere because the dev tools are under NDA, but you should have documentation on how to set up a project.

Comment: Thanks zneak ..it got me started ,and i was successfully able to compile it.Hope it works fine with the engine..fingers crossed.